# Determining all points where this function is holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, complex-numbers

Given $z=x+iy$ and $f(z)=x^3+3xy^2+i(y^3+3x^2y)$

I have to determine all points where f is holomorphic.

Since the function is a polynomial, does it not mean that it would be holomorphic everywhere?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A function is holomorphic at points the Cauchy-Riemann equations hold in a neighborhood,
which in your case only imposes
$$
-xy=xy
$$

Which requires one of $x$ or $y$ to be $0$.

This is a question about holomorphicity rather than complex differentiability. Since being holomorphic at a point requires an open ball around which the C-R equations hold, the above function is not holomorphic anywhere. It is however complex differentiable along the real and imaginary axes.